# iPhone App - Create a copy of an app with different Bundle Identifier

Tags: iphone, xcode, clone

I have an app - with soem features and th eonly thing different between this app and another app I am planning to build is the sqlite database - WHat is the simplest way to clone an entire app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate the target in Xcode and change its bundle id.